# Tornado PeriodicCallback execute at once

Tags: python, tornado

I want to do refresh a object every 10 minutes so i use `tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(myjob, 10*60*1000)` BUT the first execution is 10 minute later. Is there some setting to make `myjob` running at **0 min**,10 min, 20min .....?

```
class Store(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def load(self):
        with (yield STORE_POOL.connected_client()) as client:
            data = yield client.call("HGETALL", self.static_dict_key)
            self.data = {data[i].decode("utf-8"): int(data[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(data), 2)}


def main():
    ...
    store = Store()
    # ----> Do i need to add some code here? [1]
    backjob = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(store.load, BACKJOB_TIME)
    backjob.start()
```

Do i need to add some code in [1]?
I guess there will be 2 plans:
1> change some setting in `PeriodicCallback()`.
2> execute store.load once before PeriodicCallback() BUT I have no idea about how to run a job synchronously with `@tornado.gen.coroutine` only once.

Comment: 1. [It has no such setting](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/ioloop.html#PeriodicCallback). 2. Just `tornado.ioloop.add_callback(store.load)` at it will be invoked as soon as ioloop is started.

Comment: @Fian Thanks for the reply!It can work! Thanks a lot.I need to read document more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common and I've written similar functions for convenience. Here's a simple way of adding variably timed execution:

```
from tornado import ioloop

class VariableFire(object):

    def __init__(self, max_delay, increment_by):
        """
        :param max_delay: Max number of seconds.
        :param increment_by: Increment delay per interval until max is hit.
        """
        self.max_delay = max_delay
        self.increment_by = increment_by
        self.delay = 1

    def fire(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        # execute
        fn(*args, **kwargs)

        # get the delay interval
        delay = self.delay

        if self.delay < self.max_delay:
            # increment the delay by certain amount
            self.delay += self.increment_by
        elif delay > self.max_delay:
            # reset value to max_delay
            self.delay = delay = self.max_delay

        ioloop.IOLoop.current().call_later(delay, self.fire, fn, *args, **kwargs)


variable = VariableFire(max_delay = 30, increment_by = 3)
variable.fire(print, 'Hello World')

ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

If you're clever, you can make it into a decorator and use it on functions directly but for the sake of simplicity...

> 1> change some setting in PeriodicCallback().

Can't do it with PeriodicCallback but with my example, you could change the intervals at a later time.

> 2> execute store.load once before PeriodicCallback() BUT I have no
>   idea about how to run a job synchronously with @tornado.gen.coroutine
>   only once.

If you decide to use code similar to my example, you could just run:

```
variable.fire(store.load)
```